# Importing a script that contains relative imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Sorry in advance if this *relative import* question seems like something that was posted here before. I saw a few similar questions but none have solved my issue.

I have a directory with 2 files:

```
mydir/
  foo.py
  bar.py
```

The content of `foo.py` is:

```
print("inside foo.py")

class Foo:
    pass
```

And the content of `bar.py` contains a **relative import**:

```
print("importing foo.py from a relative path")
from .foo import Foo
print("Successfully imported foo.py")
```

When trying to run `python3 bar.py` from inside the directory, or `python3 mydir/bar.py` from outside the directory, I am getting:
`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

My question is: **How can I run `python3 bar.py` successfully?**

Note that
I am not allowed to change the files, but I can add additional files like `__init__.py` with weird hacks.

Comment: Remove the dot from `from .foo import Foo` and it should work

Comment: He has mentioned that he isn't allowed to edit bar and foo files

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a relative import in this case as you have no files outside of mydir that would be the main module.

As you cannot edit the files `foo.py` and `bar.py` instead add a file outside mydir,

```
test.py
mydir/
  foo.py
  bar.py
```

`test.py`,

```
import mydir.bar
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I prefer a solution that will allow to run the file directly: `python3 bar.py`

Answer (score 1):

Relative imports are for modules that are inside a package. In your case, this package would be `mydir`. To do that, requires you to either `import` from outside the package, or run it directly with the `-m` switch.

So from one directory up of mydir, **run `python3 -m mydir.bar`**

For older versions of Python you'd need to add an `__init__.py` in mydir, which can be empty.